# SQLITE order by numeric and not alphabetic

Tags: sqlite, numeric, sql-order-by

When I order my database SQLITE by Classement I have this :

```
Classement | Nom
1          | clem
10         | caro
11         | flo
12         | raph
2          | prisc
3          | karim
4          | prout
```

I would like to get :

```
Classement | Nom
1          | clem
2          | prisc
3          | karim
4          | prout
10         | caro
11         | flo
12         | raph
```

Here is my code :

```
SELECT t.Classement 
FROM tableau t 
WHERE 1 = (SELECT 1 + COUNT (*) FROM tableau t2 WHERE t2.Classement < t.Classement OR ( t2.Classement == t.Classement AND t2.Nom < t.Nom ))
```

Can anyone help me ?
Thank you!

Comment: Resolved problem,it came from my column which was a text and not an integer ! thanks all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get alphabetic order if the values are strings.

To change the table so that all `Classement` values are numbers, ensure that the column type is not a text type, and use this:

```
UPDATE tableau SET Classement = CAST(Classement AS NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 8):

I guess column Classement is not an integer but character. So try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableau ORDER BY cast(Classement as integer);
```