# SQLite Ordering Whole Numbers

Tags: sqlite

I am fairly aware that ORDER BY in SQLite puts the number in Ascending order unless DESC is at the end. But I realized that it only worked for the starting numbers.

```
i.e 
INT
14
78
357
2999
57
888

ORDER BY INT

Gives
14
2999
357
57
78
888
```

Is it possible to use the ORDER BY function where the whole numbers are in ascending Order?

```
As such
14
57
78
357    
888
2999
```

Comment: It seems like you have *text*, not numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLITE order by numeric and not alphabetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467140/sqlite-order-by-numeric-and-not-alphabetic)

Answer (score 0):

```
select (INT * 1)  as "int_number" from mytable order by 1
```

or as someone points out in the link:

```
select INT from mytable order by (cast INT as Integer)
```